# Visual Studio 2017 won't compile my ASP.NET web project, saying "could not load file or assembly" for a library that is definitely being referenced

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

**Current Situation:**

- I have an ASP.NET web project. (Framework Version: .NET Framework 4.5.2)
- One developer here is able to compile it and run it fine in Visual Studio 2017.
- I cannot, I get the "could not load file or assembly" error for a reference that is in my list of references.

**Screenshots:**

Error:
[image: Error Message]

Bin Folder:

[image: Bin Folder]

Web.config Potential Relevant Sections:
[image: DevExpress Section Group]
[image: DevExpress Controls]
[image: Assemblies]
[image: Handlers & Modules]
[image: More Handlers & Modules]
[image: devExpress Section]

DevExpress Licenses File:
[image: DevExpress License]

DevExpress Library File's Details:
[image: Library File Details]

**Things I've Tried:**

- Clean Solution & Rebuild Solution
- Deleted solution locally and clean get of solution from source control
- Clearing out my temp directory
- Opening the project in Visual Studio 2015
- Having the developer zip up his local copy of the solution / project and sending it to me (When I ran his copy locally I continued to get the same error.)
- Re-adding the existing library it's complaining about
- Manually deleting and re-adding all the libraries in my BIN folder
- Messing with the license file, web.config, and assembly references in code (including adjusting the version numbers because for some reason the version number is 17.2.5.0 anywhere it's referenced in the project, but the file's Details actually says it's 17.2.9.0?)
- Smashing my face into my keyboard...

...Always the same error.

**Additional Information**

- Other developers run into the same exact error under the same conditions as me, only my one developer who's been working in this project can build it fine
- I just noticed that on a new copy of the work project, my references window is showing 2 of the same reference to the DevExpress.Data library (one in the GAC and one in the BIN) but when I try re-adding the reference to my project, the one in the BIN disappears from my references window:

[image: DevExpress References Before]

[image: DevExpress References After]

Comment: Did windows block the DLL file?

Comment: I don't think so (this actually use to compile for me about a year+ ago -it's been a while since I've try to build it.) But how can I check anyway?

Comment: What do you mean deployed to my local GAC? (I know some of my references sometimes live in the GAC but I don't really know what that means.)

Comment: try deleting obj folder?

Comment: @ranton187 Where's the obj folder located?

Comment: beside the bin folder..

Comment: @ranton187 Deleting the obj folder from the secondary project (which is a console app in the same solution that the web project is dependent on, there is no obj folder for the primary web project) allowed me to rebuild successfully the first time, but then it wouldn't run and it wouldn't rebuild again and kept giving me a new error about the same assembly that said "Could not load file or assembly DevExpress.Data.v17.2, Version=17.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=*****' or one of it's dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."